# Db link between Oracle & MSSQL causing issue with Varchar2(2000) column

Tags: sql-server, oracle

We have a DB Link from Oracle DB (v12.2.0.1.0) to MSSQL DB (2012).

There is a table in MSSQL DB which contains a column with datatype Varchar2(2000).

While trying to select from that table using the DB Link from Oracle DB we are getting `WIDEMEMO` as display.

While doing anything using that table we are facing the error

> ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype

We even tried creating a local table using `Create Table x as Select * from y@dblink`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL Server does not have a "Varchar2" datatype.

Comment: Varchar2 belongs to Oracle.  The equivalent datatype in SqlServer would most likely be NVarchar. Try explicitly casting the datatypes in the query rather than letting the compilers do it on their own.